# Function button: Unhide cells between values and hide all other rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have read through the questions/answers posted here and did not find one that quite matched what I am looking for. I am relatively new to macros and this one is proving to be a bit of a challenge for me.

I am building a template that contains several sections.

What I need:
I have all the sections listed one after the other in this spreadsheet with keywords typed in between. One of them, for example, is called "Management Testing". In the row above this section I typed "T*MaTes". On the row below this section, I typed "U*Fin". What I need is a macro that will look for the first word, locate it, then look for the second word, select all rows in between and unhide them while keeping all the other sections hidden.
Then I will apply that macro to all the other sections to be able to display one at the time while hiding all the others, depending on which option button gets chosen.

The reason I need a macro based on key words is because the sections may get edited at times, (rows added/deleted, etc) which means that any macro for hiding/unhiding rows based on the row number will fail.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
Sub ManagementTesting()

Dim 1FirstHit           As Long

Dim 1SecondHit          As Long

Do While True
      1FirstHit = getItemLocation("T*MaTes", Columns(1), , False)
      If (1FirstHit = 0) Then Exit Do
      1SecondHit = getItemLocation("U*Fin", Range(Cells(lFirstHit + 1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)), , False)
      If (1SecondHit = 0) Then Exit Do
      Rows(1FirstHit & ":" & lSecondHit).EntireRow.Hidden = True
EndSub
```

Not sure where to take it from here... your help and guidance will be very much appreciated!!! Thank you!!!!

Marta

Comment: Not a solution, but you cant start variable names with numbers. Could you include the code for the `getItemLocation` function too?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your code to work, but the general idea is good (assuming my guess of what `getItemLocation` does is right)

The following code is a different approach, instead of searching for the start, then the end, it loops over the whole document (which would be changed) and can [b]un[/b]hide multiple groups (or just a single one by editing `SingleInstance`).

```
Sub Main()
Dim Index As Integer: Index = 1 ' Where to start the search from
Dim Found As Boolean: Found = False
Dim SingleInstance As Boolean: SingleInstance = False ' Stop after the first instance
Dim Start As Integer
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' The worksheet your data is on

' This will hide groups (multiple) of rows.
' It searches column 1 for keywords "StartGroup" and "EndGroup"
' Eg- Sheet1
' 1: StartGroup
' 2: [Hidden] ExampleData
' 3: [Hidden] ExampleData
' 4: EndGroup
' 5: StartGroup
' 6: [Hidden] ExampleData
' 7: EndGroup

' Running this code with that data will unhide rows 2-3 and rows 6-6 (including the start and end group indicators)



Do
    ' Test to see if the current iteration indicates the start of a group
    If Sheet.Cells(Index, 1).Value2 = "StartGroup" Then
        Start = Index ' remember the location
        Found = True  ' remember that we've found a group
    Else
        ' Skip if we are not currently in a group
        If Found = True Then
            ' Test to see if it is the end of a group
            If Sheet.Cells(Index, 1).Value2 = "EndGroup" Then
                ' unhide the rows
                Sheet.Range(Sheet.Rows(Start), Sheet.Rows(Index)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                ' reset Found and wait for the next group of EOF
                Found = False
                If SingleInstance = True Then Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            ' I added an EOF indicator just to exit quicker from the loop past my test data
            If Sheet.Cells(Index, 1).Value2 = "EndFile" Then Exit Do
        End If
    End If

    ' Debugging - Infinite Loops are mean!
    If Index < 1000 Then
        Index = Index + 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This is the macro I created. Thank you Nickfor your response!

```
Sub MaTes() 
Rows("8:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = True 
Dim Index As Integer: Index = 9 
Dim I As Integer 
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 
For Index = 1 To 1000 
If Sheet.Cells(Index, 1).Value2 = "T*MaTes" Then 
I = Index + 1 
For I = Index To 1000 
If Sheet.Cells(I, 1).Value2 = "U*Fin" Then 
Sheet.Range(Sheet.Rows(Index), Sheet.Rows(I)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Exit For 
Else: I = I + 1 
End If 
Next 
Else: Index = Index + 1 
End If 
Next 
For Index = 1 To 1000 
If Sheet.Cells(Index, 1).Value2 = "A*Sum" Then 
I = Index + 1 
For I = Index To 1000 
If Sheet.Cells(I, 1).Value2 = "T*Mates" Then 
Sheet.Range(Sheet.Rows(Index), Sheet.Rows(I)).EntireRow.Hidden = True 
Exit For 
Else: I = I + 1 
End If 
Next 
Else: Index = Index + 1 
End If 
Next 

End Sub
```